# Separar una lista intercalada

Tags: python

Como se podría dividir esta lista de manera intercalada

lista = [1, 15, 0, 13, 15, 10, 13, 18,1]

en un resultado
como:

a = [1,0,15,13,1]
b = [15,13,10,18]

Comment: Bienvenido Oscar... Que has intentado? Seria bueno ver un poco de tu código para partir desde ahí... Por favor, date una vuelta por [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y así evitar reportes o puntuaciones negativas.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear un for que tome los elementos pares e impares de tu lista, es decir:

```
lista = [1, 15, 0, 13, 15, 10, 13, 18,1]
a=[]
b=[]
contador=0
for element in lista:
    if contador % 2 == 0:
        a.append(element)
    else:
        b.append(element)
    contador+=1
print(a,b)
```

O usar slicing:

```
lista = [1, 15, 0, 13, 15, 10, 13, 18,1]
a=lista[0::2]
b=lista[1::2]
```

Comment: El código lo divide tal cual pusiste. ¿Cómo requieres separarlo entonces?

Comment: También puedes usar slicing para lograrlo: a=lista[1::2]